# IF MIN or IF AVERAGE on an integer identifier

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I am trying to use a MIN IF on a number, but my problem is that the comparison is a comparison between numbers and returns me `0`, which is not correct.

I tried the following two formulas and get the same results:

```
=MIN(IF(D3=$A$2:$A$13;$B$2:$B$13;))
=AVERAGE(IF(D3=$A$2:$A$13;$B$2:$B$13;))
```

[image]

Any suggestions, how to solve this issue, by doing a MIN or AVERAGE on an integer identifier.

Comment: @pancho018 Yep! Just edited my question, but I still get wrong outputs...

Comment: Are you pressing `ctrl`+`shift`+`enter` after you're done editing the formula, instead of just `enter`?

Comment: not sure where youre getting those values from for your wanted outcome i would suggest the first problem is the numbers stored as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a MINIF use this standard [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF),

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, B2:B6/(A2:A6=D3), 1)
```

The conditional average can be handled by the [AVERAGEIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-ff3c70f9-5afe-4d3e-87d4-717187f98c20).

```
=AVERAGEIF(A2:A6, D3, B2:B6)
```

The results for your sample data are -32.54 and -11.48666667.

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>